# Strings - setting it globally

Tags: java, string, global-variables, globalization

Okay so i created this program which is unfinished that allows you to insert a students name and test score into a string. But my probably is, im trying to use if statements so that the user is able to type in a number and choose what they wish to do.

Im trying to have it so after the user has inserted the name and test score, they can choose to have the name and test score printed out, or they can quit or insert another name but i cant because the string is not set globally.

does anyone know how to do this? Thank You,

```
package week14;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task4 {
    private static Scanner input;
        private static Scanner input2;

        public static void main (String [] args){
            input2 = new Scanner (System.in);

            System.out.println("Student Mark Program");
            System.out.println("\nHere are your options:");
            System.out.println("\n1. Insert Student name and mark");
            System.out.println("2. Quit");

        int choice = input2.nextInt();
            System.out.println();

                if (choice == 1){
                    opt1();
                }
                else if (choice == 2){
                    quit();
                }
        }

                public static void opt1(){

                input = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String firstname;
                        String surname;

                int score1;
                System.out.print("Enter the students first name: ");
                firstname = input.next();

                System.out.print("Enter the students surname: ");
                surname = input.next();

                String full_name;
                full_name = firstname + " " + surname;

                System.out.println("Please enter students score: ");
                score1 = input.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Name : " + full_name);
                System.out.println("Score: " + score1);

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("\nHere are your options:");
                System.out.println("\n1. Insert Another Student name");
                System.out.println("2. Get student name");
                System.out.println("3. Get student name and mark");
                System.out.println("4. Quit");

                int choice = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println();

                if (choice == 1){
                    opt6();
                }
                else if (choice == 2){
                    opt2();
                }
                else if (choice == 3){
                    opt3();
                }

                System.out.println();
                input.close();
                }



                public static void opt2(){

                System.out.println("Name : " + full_name);

                }

                public static void opt3(){


                }

                public static void opt4(){

                }

                public static void opt5 (){

                }

                public static void opt6 (){

                }

                public static void quit(){
                    System.out.println("You have quit the program");
                    System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this `static String full_name;` under where you declare `private static Scanner input2;` in your class. Not necessarily good programming practice to use global variables, but for your purposes it will likely get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would initialize a new global variable set your full_name to and return it as an accessor method.

```
public static String getName()
{
    return (nameOfString);
}
```

Also, I see that you want to make an other command to change your name and you could do that with a settor method.

```
public static void setName(String newName)
{
    originalString = newName;
}
```